# Laravel v9.x incorrect created_at time

Tags: laravel, datetime, timestamp, migration, crud

I'm using `$table->timestamps()` for my tables.

The problem is when I create a new record, the `created_at` column datetime is different from column `updated_at` and also it's set to 2 days in the past.

```
created_at -> 2022-05-05 15:47:43
updated_at -> 2022-05-07 10:42:44
```

The `updated_at` is correct. I also overridden `freshTimestamp` method in the model.

```
public function freshTimestamp() {
    return Carbon::now()->timestamp;
}
```

**Update :** Added `order` migration `up` method.

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('orders', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('amount');    
        $table->timestamp('expires_at');    
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be on your column timestamp (for example sql server could have different time than web server) so please show the sql or migration code.

Comment: Sorry but if you need more information on this, you should ask it in the comments not in an answer. I'll update my question details asap.

Comment: Yes thats true but also had a clue to answer thats why i postetd as answer. By the code I can only assume the column is changed during save (or model boot). I would log the timestamps before model save on the controller to narrow it down.

Comment: For now, I stopped using laravels ```timestamps``` and I created my own ```created_at``` and ```updated_at``` columns.